# Sticky header snapping to top to early

Tags: javascript, css, scrolltop, sticky

I've been playing around with this code forever.  I have a sticky nav implemented on my site and it's supposed to activate once the header becomes out of sight when the user scrolls.  The header div is above the nav div.  The sticky part works fine but it activates too soon. It snaps to the top immediately once I start scrolling and then doesn't snap back to it's original position once the header comes into view again.

Here's the jquery that makes it work:

```
(function($) {

  var $body,
    $target,
    targetoffsetTop,
    resizetimer,
    stickyclass = 'sticky'

  function updateCoords() {
    targetoffsetTop = $target.offset().top
  }

  function makesticky() {                     //Sets the sticky class to activate once  
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop()   //the scroll offset is greater than 
    if (scrollTop >= targetoffsetTop) {        //how far the div is from the top.
      if (!$body.hasClass(stickyclass)) {
        $body.addClass(stickyclass)
      }
    } else {                        
      if ($body.hasClass(stickyclass)) {
        $body.removeClass(stickyclass)
      }
    }
  }

  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $body = $(document.body)
    $target = $('#header_lg')              //This is the target div that get's sticky
    updateCoords()
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      requestAnimationFrame(makesticky)
    })
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
      clearTimeout(resizetimer)
      resizetimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $body.removeClass(stickyclass)
        updateCoords()
        makesticky()
      }, 50)
    })
  })

})(jQuery)
```

CSS:

```
#header_lg {          //Before sticky
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  padding: .7%;
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s, width 1s;
  -moz-transition: height 1s, width 1s;
  transition: height 1s, width 1s;
}
body.sticky #header_lg {   //After sticky
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I'm fairly new with javascript so any suggestions from you experts as to why the code isn't working right would be greatly appreciated.  If it's important, the page is in a bootstrap format so it's within the `visible-lg` class with a `container` class inside that set to `style="width:100%; margin:0; padding:0;"`.  The HTML code is just an empty div with some filler text.

Comment: I tried your code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqKvGj?editors=1000). it doesnt stick but it activates at the right time...?

Comment: huh that's strange...the sticky part is actually because my comments were in the wrong format so I just removed them and the code worked fine...any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: @GCyrillus 's example using your code with fixed comments works for me. If your implementation still isnt working including that fix I am not sure what it could be. One thing I noticed while doing the same thing was that some browser used a different variable for the offset value, what browser are you using?

Comment: @Toni i used FF W7..  checked with  latest : opera/chrome/IE works.  OLd win Safari 5.1.7.(7534.57.2) fails ! but does any one still uses this one ? :)

Comment: Would it have anything to do with the fact that it's in a bootstrap container?  I also have margins set on that container which was causing some conflicts as well where the header would ignore the right margin once it became sticky and extend to the right edge. If there's nothing wrong with the sticky code then it's gotta be some conflict with the bootstrap @GCyrillus

Comment: @Toni I want your opinion too but I could only tag one user in my comment lol

Comment: Well, could you set a fiddle or codepen with your actual code (and fake text/image eventually to keep it discret :) ) so we can see as well what you are dealing with. Yes , bootsrap can be in the way CSS or JS involved can overwrite some of your css/js beside do you know about position:sticky and polyfills ready made ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699943/sticky-overlay-at-bottom-of-scrolling-div/35700259?answer=#answer-35700259

Answer (score 0):

you did not write correctly your CSS comments *(different from js)*:

[try this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGBrev):**(thanks @Toni for her usefull pen here i forked to demonstrate )**

```
#header_lg {          /*Before sticky*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  padding: .7%;
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s, width 1s;
  -moz-transition: height 1s, width 1s;
  transition: height 1s, width 1s;
}
body.sticky #header_lg {   /*After sticky*/
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Her* and I wouldn't have minded regardless but thank you for the attribution!

Comment: No problem, I get that a lot, maybe I should start going by my middle name online lol