# Sticky overlay at bottom of scrolling div

Tags: css

I've got a scrollable container. I want an overlay to stick to the bottom of this container, but it should only cover the contents of the scrollable area, it should not cover the scrollbar. 
Desired result:

[image]

With my current solution the problem is that the overlay also covers the scrollbar.

I COULD solve the issue by setting pixel values for 'width' and 'right' of the overlay. But I don't want to have to do that.

```css
 .container {
      position: relative;
      border: solid 1px red;
      height: 100px;
      width: 200px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 16px;
    }
        
    .scrollable {
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .overlay {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      background: rgba(100, 200, 10, 0.5);
    }
```

```html
<section class="container">
        <div class="scrollable">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia maxime facere quae cumque perferendis cum atque quia repellendus rerum eaque quod quibusdam incidunt blanditiis possimus temporibus reiciendis deserunt sequi eveniet necessitatibus
        maiores quas assumenda voluptate qui odio laboriosam totam repudiandae? Doloremque dignissimos voluptatibus eveniet rem quasi minus ex cumque esse culpa cupiditate cum architecto! Facilis deleniti unde suscipit minima obcaecati vero ea soluta odio
        cupiditate placeat vitae nesciunt quis alias dolorum nemo sint facere. Deleniti itaque incidunt eligendi qui nemo corporis ducimus beatae consequatur est iusto dolorum consequuntur vero debitis saepe voluptatem impedit sint ea numquam quia voluptate
        quidem.
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
      position: relative;
      border: solid 1px red;
      height: 100px;
      width: 200px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 16px;
    }
        
    .scrollable {
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .scrollable p {
      z-index:-2;
      position:relative;
      }

    .overlay {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
width:100%;
      height: 30px;
      background: rgba(100, 200, 10, 0.5);
      z-index:-1;
    }
```

```html
<section class="container">
        <div class="scrollable">
       <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia maxime facere quae cumque perferendis cum atque quia repellendus rerum eaque quod quibusdam incidunt blanditiis possimus temporibus reiciendis deserunt sequi eveniet necessitatibus
        maiores quas assumenda voluptate qui odio laboriosam totam repudiandae? Doloremque dignissimos voluptatibus eveniet rem quasi minus ex cumque esse culpa cupiditate cum architecto! Facilis deleniti unde suscipit minima obcaecati vero ea soluta odio
        cupiditate placeat vitae nesciunt quis alias dolorum nemo sint facere. Deleniti itaque incidunt eligendi qui nemo corporis ducimus beatae consequatur est iusto dolorum consequuntur vero debitis saepe voluptatem impedit sint ea numquam quia voluptate
        quidem.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: it is mentioned in question not to use pixel value for `right`

Comment: Sorry, see my updated answer. It is an improvement on the response of @iyyapan

Comment: Doesn't work in IE11 with `.container {height: auto}` or `default`. Overlay scrolls away with it's neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your codes.

Please try it.

```
.overlay {z-index: -1;}
```

Answer (score -1):

`position:sticky;` could be used :

> ***(quotes from [sitepoint  introduction to sticky](http://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/))***
>
> See position: [sticky on Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)… for all the details.
>   Fortunately there a number of polyfills to choose from:
>
> [fixed-sticky](https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky) by the Filament Group (requires jQuery)
>
> [position–sticky](https://github.com/matthewp/position--sticky-)- by Matthew Phillips (Uses Modernizr for detection)
>
> [position: sticky](http://philipwalton.github.io/polyfill/demos/position-sticky/), part of Philip Walton’s Polyfill.js library
>
> [position: sticky CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/xLakC) by Fabrice Weinberg (requires jQuery)
>
> [Stickyfill](http://wd.dizaina.net/en/scripts/stickyfill/) by Oleg Korsunsky (IE9+)

```css
 .container {
      position: relative;
      border: solid 1px red;
      height: 100px;
      width: 200px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 16px;
    }
        
    .scrollable {
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: scroll;
position: relative;
    }

    .overlay {
      position: sticky;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      background: rgba(100, 200, 10, 0.5);
    }
```

```html
<section class="container">
        <div class="scrollable">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia maxime facere quae cumque perferendis cum atque quia repellendus rerum eaque quod quibusdam incidunt blanditiis possimus temporibus reiciendis deserunt sequi eveniet necessitatibus
        maiores quas assumenda voluptate qui odio laboriosam totam repudiandae? Doloremque dignissimos voluptatibus eveniet rem quasi minus ex cumque esse culpa cupiditate cum architecto! Facilis deleniti unde suscipit minima obcaecati vero ea soluta odio
        cupiditate placeat vitae nesciunt quis alias dolorum nemo sint facere. Deleniti itaque incidunt eligendi qui nemo corporis ducimus beatae consequatur est iusto dolorum consequuntur vero debitis saepe voluptatem impedit sint ea numquam quia voluptate
        quidem.
<div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        
</section>
```

Scrollbar is average `1em` wide, you can give a try using only coordonates to size the width of this overlay.

```css
.container {
      position: relative;
      border: solid 1px red;
      height: 100px;
      width: 200px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 16px;
    }
        
    .scrollable {
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .overlay {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 1em;
      left:0;
      height: 30px;
      background: rgba(100, 200, 10, 0.5);
    }
```

```html
<section class="container">
        <div class="scrollable">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia maxime facere quae cumque perferendis cum atque quia repellendus rerum eaque quod quibusdam incidunt blanditiis possimus temporibus reiciendis deserunt sequi eveniet necessitatibus
        maiores quas assumenda voluptate qui odio laboriosam totam repudiandae? Doloremque dignissimos voluptatibus eveniet rem quasi minus ex cumque esse culpa cupiditate cum architecto! Facilis deleniti unde suscipit minima obcaecati vero ea soluta odio
        cupiditate placeat vitae nesciunt quis alias dolorum nemo sint facere. Deleniti itaque incidunt eligendi qui nemo corporis ducimus beatae consequatur est iusto dolorum consequuntur vero debitis saepe voluptatem impedit sint ea numquam quia voluptate
        quidem.
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
</section>
```

screenshot in Chrome: [image]

Comment: Nope. In chrome, the sticky-solution doesn't work at all - '.overlay' stops working as an overlay, instead it's placed under the scrollable contents and you gotta scroll to the bottom of the scrollable area to see it. Also, the assumption that scrollbars are 1em is not true for Chrome on windows 7 - '.overlay' ends up on top of the scrollbar by about 3px

Comment: @Drkawashima just like CSS3 features did at first (border-radius and so on) , but there is polyfill http://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/ and the avearge 1em width of scrollbar is from ever anyway :( a compromise has to be found or js to be used for eventually pixel perfect :) )  position:sticky is going to be something you'll use in a short time ... browsers gets updated quiet often nowdays

Comment: @Drkawashima http://i.stack.imgur.com/IfzNY.jpg in chrome it is fine, unless you played with font-size value, so you need to adjust to it ...